# Where to `Exit(1)` and where to return error?

Tags: go, error-handling, idioms

What is the idiomatic way to handle errors occurred deep in a program layers? If I have such a snippet somewhere deep inside a package:

```
file, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {            
    os.Exit(1) // or return errors.New("The path is invalid.")
}
```

Should I return an error and possibly drag it through a several layers with `if {} else {}` blocks up to `main` and `Exit` in `main` or `Exit` immediately?

With immediate `Exit` code looks cleaner and more readable. But sometimes it is difficult to test. With returns and checks code looks worse (at my opinion) but it is easier to test and reach 100% of coverage.

And one more question... If I'm writing a package and it has no `main` function should I leave `Exit`s to a "user" program and just return errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you better handle error in place not drug it through. You call `os.Exit()` when you need immediate exit so in place also. And you forget another option - `panic()`. It goes through and evaluates deferred function which allows you some teardown. While writing a package it's not recommended to call `os.Exit()` or `panic()` to not confuse users with unpredictable. In packages promoting errors is the best choice.